# Delete records using Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: sql-server, informatica

I have simple mapping which deletes records in the target table. I have not used "UPDATE STRATEGY" transformation, rather set session property "delete" in order to delete records.

The said table is having composite primary keys (having 10 columns). It is working fine if all these columns are having value. BUT there are few records in which one of the column has NULL value. In this scenario, it is not deleting that record.

Can someone let me know how to handle this situation?

Comment: What is the DBMS of the target table? Most DBMSs would not let you create a PK on columns that allow nulls. Can you add full CREATE TABLE statement  for the target to your question?

Comment: DBMA: MS SQL Server
It is composite Unique Index defined on it.  composed of 10 columns.

Comment: A unique index is not the same as a primary key - one of the main differences is that UKs can have null columns while PKs can't. Does your table not have a PK defined?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible, because informatica fires sql like this when deleting data - `delete from tab  where key1=v1 and key2=v2`. So, if v2 is null, its possible, delete query will ignore the record.
You can use target update override property to do this. Write your own sql to delete data.

```
DELETE FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  ID = :TU.ID 
  AND ISNULL(EMP_NAME,'Unspecified') = ISNULL(:TU.EMP_NAME,'Unspecified')
```

Since you have keys defined in infa you shouldnt face any problem. But please note that these deletes will be done on a row by row basis, so if it's a large table, and delete doesnt follow primary key index, the delete it could take time to delete each row!
[image: Example]

Comment: Can you tell me what are changes I need to make in Session. With DELETE opetion, Informatic is not taking updated SQL

If I use "Treat Source row as Update" it considers updated SQL, but getting hanged.

Comment: Treat Source row as Update - is the correct option. Can you pls run 1 row to test out the solution. If 1 ow works that means, the sql is not following index. check out pls the sql its generating in DB from SQL Server client.